# How can i display buttons in vertical using bootstrap panels?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have bootstrap panels currently buttons are displaying in inline , how can i display these buttons in vertically ?

main.html

```
<div class="col-md-3">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">Control</div>
                <div class="panel-body">
              <!--      <div class="btn-group-vertical">-->
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-rad btn-lg" style="margin-left: 10px" ng-click="recordLogs()" ng-disabled="disabledRecBtn"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-record"></span></button>
                      <!--  <br>-->
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" style="margin-left: 10px" ng-click="stopLogs()" ng-disabled="disabledStopBtn"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-stop"></span></button>
                        <!--<br>-->
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg" style="margin-left: 10px" ng-click="searchLogs()"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span></button>
                        <!--<br>-->
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg" ng-click="serverFiles()" style="margin-left: 10px"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-folder-close"></span></button>
               <!--     </div>-->
                </div>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you already have the answer there.  Use `class="btn-group-vertical"`.   And add a custom style to add space between the buttons.  [Demo](http://www.bootply.com/sFEAFVDaVe).

```
.btn-group-vertical > button{
    margin-bottom:10px;
}
```

Comment: Yeah i know so i have these buttons in col-md-3 but when i add class btn-group-vertical i have alot of space on right side , is there way to clear that white space ?

Comment: @hussain is there a reason you cannot use `col-md-1`?  The actual panel is taking up that much space, not the btn-group.

Comment: other side i just want to keep it col-md-9

Comment: i can use 2 but buttons will not be center then

Comment: @hussain You can still do that by using the `col-md-offset-*` classes.

Comment: @hussain Here look at [this](http://www.bootply.com/OwiC2rhb7J).  You need to remove `margin-left` and add `class="text-center"` to the panel-body div.

Comment: Thanks fpr the answer  `class="text-center" worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
.panel-body button {
    display: block;
    float: none;
}
```